# open a .txt file, sort it in ascending order for 3rd column and then save as a new .txt file

Tags: python, sorting

I was wondering how to open a .txt file and after sorting it for 4th column, I can save it as a new file. I know the linux terminal command for sorting:

```
sort -k3n  myfile.txt
```

but how do I save it as a new file?

how do I do the exact same thing inside a python script, as if the numpy.loadtxt will read from the original file, sort it and then read again from the new sorted file.

```
# ID x y
    6.60968219252e-05 7.56508909895e-10 40.65
    0.000196142774512 1.90541971372e-09 49.18
    0.000451120770124 3.75884511195e-09 60.78
    9.49736290045e-05 1.08754058315e-09 44.12
    0.000773197066156 5.55965157568e-09 70.64
    0.000395119768811 5.35886928694e-09 48.42
    0.000761797071911 1.1411313874e-08 42.8
    6.13793543105e-05 6.79135943796e-10 36.94
    0.0014257833689 6.69702707603e-09 91.49
    8.02798012773e-05 8.34778117262e-10 43.19
```

Thanks

Comment: what kind of data does the txt file have?

Comment: "how do I save it as a new file?" You can redirect the output to a file (instead of standard output), e.g. `sort -k4n myfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

Comment: just some rows and columns with numbers

Comment: can you show an example of the file you want to sort?

Comment: Why do you say 4th column but you posted an example with 3 columns (`# ID x y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure python solution

```
>>> import csv
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> print(open('sample.csv').read())
1,2,9,3
2,1,4,2
9,2,5,5
3,4,9,7
>>> with open('sample.csv') as fin, open('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
...   csv.writer(fout).writerows(sorted(csv.reader(fin), key=lambda x: float(x[3])))
... 
>>> print(open('out.csv').read())
2,1,4,2
1,2,9,3
9,2,5,5
3,4,9,7
```

Answer (score 1):

Original answer

```
sort -k4n  myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Expanded answer. Perhaps irrelevant with other answer but... I spent a minute writing it, so why not share it?

```
with open('source') as fin, with open('destination', 'w') as fout:
    unsorted_lines = [line.split(" ") for line in fin.readlines()]
    sorted_lines = sorted(unsorted_lines, key=lambda coord: coord[2])
    joined_lines = [' '.join(line) for line in sorted_lines]
    for line in joined_lines:
        fout.writelines(line)
```

Comment: You should probably add (or hint towards) a Python solution as well, given that it was explicitly asked in OP